# Expecting NamingException, getting NoSuchObjectException

Tags: java, web-services, error-handling, ejb-3.0, weblogic11g

I'm running Java 6 on Weblogic 11g.

I'm working on a Web Service projects that uses an EJB to communicate with a database. Currently I'm working on error-handling, and thus I tried undeploying the EJB before invoking the web service. My EJBClientHelper-class looks like this:

```
package mypackage.elkom.utils;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

import mypackage.elkom.ejb.beans.session.remote.ElkomRemote;

public class EJBClientHelper implements Serializable {

  /**
   * 
   */
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  private ElkomRemote elkomRemote;

  private static final String ELKOM_JNDI =   "ElkomBean#mypackage.ejb.beans.session.remote.ElkomRemote";

  private Context ctx;

  private void prepareEjb3Connection() throws PropsFileException, NamingException {
      // Here's code for getting the ejbProviderURL from propsfile //
      props.put("java.naming.factory.initial", weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
      props.put("java.naming.provider.url",ejbProviderURL);
      ctx = new InitialContext(props);

 }

  public void setElkomRemote(ElkomRemote elkomRemote) {
    this.elkomRemote = elkomRemote;
  }

  public ElkomRemote getElkomRemote() throws NamingException, PropsFileException {
    prepareEjb3Connection();
    if(elkomRemote == null) {
    elkomRemote = (ElkomRemote)ctx.lookup(ELKOM_JNDI);
   }
   return elkomRemote;
  }

}
```

But, when i use the getElkomRemote(); I get this message insted of NamingException:

```
SEVERE: The object identified by: '678' could not be found.  Either it was has not been exported or it has been collected by the distributed garbage collector.; 
nested exception is: java.rmi.NoSuchObjectException: The object identified by: '678' could not be found.  
Either it was has not been exported or it has been collected by the distributed garbage collector.
javax.ejb.EJBException: The object identified by: '678' could not be found.  Either it was has not been exported or it has been collected by the distributed garbage collector.; 
nested exception is: java.rmi.NoSuchObjectException: The object identified by: '678' could not be found.  
Either it was has not been exported or it has been collected by the distributed garbage collector.
java.rmi.NoSuchObjectException: The object identified by: '678' could not be found.  Either it was has not been exported or it has been collected by the distributed garbage collector.
```

Anyone know why I get this message instead of NamingException? And perhaps how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three Exception categories:

- System Exceptions
- JVM Exceptions
- Application Exceptions

Α system exception may occur due to a code bug or a misconfigured resource such as a misconfigured JNDI lookup. If an enterprise bean faces a system error it normally throws a javax.ejb.EJBException. The container wraps the EJBException in a RemoteException and finally the RemoteException is passed back to the client. That's what happened in your case and that's why you received a RemoteException.

The system exceptions cannot be handled from the client applications and should be thrown as unchecked exceptions.

For more detailed information you can see the following articles:

- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-ejbexcept/index.html
- http://java.sun.com/j2ee/tutorial/1_3-fcs/doc/BMP6.html

I hope this helps you.